# what sorting algorithm should be used when dealing with strings, numbers or both in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I find this really intriguing.

When- `var x = [1, 50, 2, 4, 2, 2, 88, 9, 10, 22, 40];`

Then `x.sort();` will **not** sort properly

When `var x = ["dog","apple","zebra","cow"];` , `x.sort();`
will sort properly.

what is the proper function to sort them in one call?

Comment: you can pass a custom sorting logic as a callback method

Comment: "will not sort properly" - maybe your definition of "properly" is wrong :-)

Answer (score 3):

You must define a custom sort and pass it as a callback to sort(). The callback is passed two arguments.

For numeric sorting:

```
x.sort(function(number1, number2) {
    return number1 - number2;
});
```

The default [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirect=no) converts each element to string and sorts lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

As per [ECMAScript 15.4.4.11 Array.prototype.sort(comparefn)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), sorting is done alphabetically by default meaning that `22` comes before `4`. It's actually a great deal more complicated in the document but that's basically what it boils down to.

If you want to sort them numerically, you need to provide your own comparison function, such as:

```
x.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

The function just has to return a negative number if `a < b`, zero if they're equal or a positive number if `a > b`.

Answer (score 0):

you should just pass in your own sorting method and sort them however you like. You can treat them as strings or numbers or anything else, as well as sort them in ascending or descending order.  Additionally, you can pass in objects and sort those objects based on specific members.  It's very rare that the generic `sort()` method will be useful by default.